# Jackson CsvMapper to map object with a map of maps to csv

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I have a complex java object that I want to map to csv using Jacksons CsvMapper.

```
public class TestObject {
  private Map<String, Map<String, String>> values;
  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getValues() {
      return values;
  }

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setValues(Map<String, Map<String, String>> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

}
```

The object is a list of TestObjects:

```
 CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper(); 
 CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(clazz).withUseHeader(true);
 
 ObjectWriter myObjectWriter = mapper.writer(schema);
 return myObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(objectList);
```

However when I try to map this to csv, I get an error due to the values in the map since its a map of map.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMappingException: Unrecognized column 'test_column': known columns: ....
```

Does anyone know how I can get jacksons csvmapper to correctly convert this map of maps to csv?

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem. Full example [here](https://itexpertsconsultant.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/how-to-readwrite-csv-file-to-map-in-java/)

```
/**
 * @param listOfMap
 * @param writer
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void csvWriter(List<HashMap<String, String>> listOfMap, Writer writer) throws IOException {
    CsvSchema schema = null;
    CsvSchema.Builder schemaBuilder = CsvSchema.builder();
    if (listOfMap != null && !listOfMap.isEmpty()) {
        for (String col : listOfMap.get(0).keySet()) {
            schemaBuilder.addColumn(col);
        }
        schema = schemaBuilder.build().withLineSeparator(System.lineSeparator()).withHeader();
    }
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    mapper.writer(schema).writeValues(writer).writeAll(listOfMap);
    writer.flush();
}
```